# Trouble with Java waiting

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, animation, sleep

I am trying to animate a character, but I'm not quite sure how to get `sleep()` to work. The idea is that the image will change every second until the animation is over. As of now, if you press the space bar, the animation should run. Here's what I have so far:

```
Image[] imageArray = new Image[4];
imageArray[0] = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "Death1.png");
imageArray[1] = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "Death2.png");
imageArray[2] = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "Death3.png");
imageArray[3] = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "Death4.png");

for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) { //Or any Loops
    try {
        //player is just where the image is stored & painted
        player = imageArray[i];
        repaint();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
}
```

Comment: If I didn't explain it well enough, let me know! I'm new to this :-)

Comment: I think what you really need to is do a search on "Swing" and "Thread.sleep" - to which you'll probably be pointed to things like [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) because this question gets asked half a dozen times a day and the answer is almost always the same

Comment: [An example search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+thread.sleep)

Comment: @FrankRodriguez you need to be aware of the existence of the Main Thread and how the drawing really works. The Drawing happens in the Main Thread and by using sleep you are blocking it which can result to drops in Frames Per Second (FPS).

Answer (score 0):

Calling `repaint` doesn't repaint the component immediately. It just generates an event which gets added to the event queue. The event queue will be processed later.

Sleeping means that you never proceed to the point where the event queue will be processed. You are just adding the repaint event four times.

You probably want to create a new Thread. This thread runs your code and is independent to the main thread. The main thread can handle all events and your thread can sleep.